# Shell - replace only number on specific line with number from another file

Tags: shell, unix, replace, hp-ux

I am working on a Shell script and I need to replace only number on line 13 with a number from another file.

**file1**:

> ```
> line1
> line2
> ...
> Text: 95%
> ...
> ```

**file2**:

> 98.4256

The result should look like this:

**file1**:

> ```
> ...   
> Text: 98.4256%
> ...
> ```

Basically I need to replace the number before % in file1 on line 13 with a number from file2 (the number in file2 is on line 1).

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "4 s/:.*/: $(cat file2)%/" file1
line1
line2
...
Text: 98.4256%
...
```

Change 4 to any other number of your requirement.

Contents of file1

```
cat file1
line1
line2
...
Text: 95%
...
```

Contents of file2

```
cat file2
98.4256
```

Comment: Thank you. As I wanted to save the changes as well, and cannot use `-i` on my HP-UX system, I was able to save the changes with this "workaround":                                                                                                 `sed "4 s/:.*/: $(cat file2)%/" file1 > file1.tmp && mv file1.tmp file1`